# Travel Blog Plugins

Tags: plugins, google-maps

I'm using Wordpress to create a blog of my travels later on this year. I would like the blog to have the following features

- my posts to be geo-located
- a map containing the locations of my posts
- ability to click individual points on the map to get to the post.

I am looking for the best/most appropriate plugins to use.

Thanks,
Al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think GeoMashup is the go-to plugin for something like this. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-mashup/

I've used it for a similar site with great results. There's a lot to dig into, it's very flexible, but you'll definitely be able to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Dalton, surprising that I couldn't find this via WP's plugins page. Possibly using the wrong search terms.